# Delete duplicates from a postgresql table without an ID field

Tags: postgresql

I have a table without an id or primary key field:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test
(
    time       TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    bid_volume INTEGER,
    bid_price  DOUBLE PRECISION,
    ask_price  DOUBLE PRECISION,
    ask_volume INTEGER
);
```

I have a number of rows which have duplicate timestamps:

```
# SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY time;
             time              | bid_volume | bid_price | ask_price | ask_volume 
-------------------------------+------------+-----------+-----------+------------
 2021-02-01 08:00:00.123457+00 |         99 |   1256.25 |    1256.5 |         75
 2021-02-01 08:00:00.123457+00 |        100 |   1256.25 |    1256.5 |         75
 2021-02-01 08:00:00.123457+00 |        100 |   1256.25 |    1256.5 |         76
 2021-02-01 08:00:00.123457+00 |        100 |    1256.5 |    1256.5 |         76
 2021-02-01 08:00:01.1227+00   |        100 |    1256.5 |    1256.5 |         76
 2021-02-01 08:01:01.126343+00 |         80 |    1257.5 |    1256.5 |         76
(6 rows)
```

I would like to delete all but one of the duplicate timestamps.

My investigations thus far lead me to believe I can use `ROW_NUMBER()` with a `PARTITION`, and delete all rows with `rn` > 1

```
test=# SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY time) AS rn, * FROM test;
 rn |             time              | bid_volume | bid_price | ask_price | ask_volume 
----+-------------------------------+------------+-----------+-----------+------------
  1 | 2021-02-01 08:00:00.123457+00 |         99 |   1256.25 |    1256.5 |         75
  2 | 2021-02-01 08:00:00.123457+00 |        100 |   1256.25 |    1256.5 |         75
  3 | 2021-02-01 08:00:00.123457+00 |        100 |   1256.25 |    1256.5 |         76
  4 | 2021-02-01 08:00:00.123457+00 |        100 |    1256.5 |    1256.5 |         76
  1 | 2021-02-01 08:00:01.1227+00   |        100 |    1256.5 |    1256.5 |         76
  1 | 2021-02-01 08:01:01.126343+00 |         80 |    1257.5 |    1256.5 |         76
```

There are several questions on SO which seem to be related:

- [deleting-all-duplicate-rows-but-keeping-one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025367/t-sql-deleting-all-duplicate-rows-but-keeping-one/6025929)
- [how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)
- [delete-using-cte-slower-than-using-temp-table-in-postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751276/delete-using-cte-slower-than-using-temp-table-in-postgres)

However, all these questions use an additional `id` field.

Without an additional `id` field I am unable to keep one of the rows:

```
# DELETE FROM test del
USING 
( 
    SELECT 
        time, 
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY time) AS rn
    FROM test
) sub
WHERE 
    sub.time = del.time
AND 
    sub.rn > 1;
```

This deletes all duplicate rows (ie: the `sub.rn > 1` doesn't seem to have any effect)

```
# SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY time;
             time              | bid_volume | bid_price | ask_price | ask_volume 
-------------------------------+------------+-----------+-----------+------------
 2021-02-01 08:00:01.1227+00   |        100 |    1256.5 |    1256.5 |         76
 2021-02-01 08:01:01.126343+00 |         80 |    1257.5 |    1256.5 |         76
```

Notice timestamp `2021-02-01 08:00:00.123457+00` is gone!

Dropping the `sub.time = del.time` clause causes **all** the rows to be deleted! (again, `sub.rn` doesn't seem to have any effect)

```
# DELETE FROM test del
USING 
( 
    SELECT 
        time, 
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY time) AS rn
    FROM test
) sub
WHERE 
    sub.rn > 1;
```

> `DELETE 6`   <-- Oh no!

How can I delete the duplicates from my table, keeping one?

Comment: Next time: make sure your table has a Primary Key. [theoretically, a table without a PK has no meaning]

Comment: basically the timestamps is the id field.

Comment: @wildplasser as Jasen said, timestamps is the id field, but sometimes there are duplicates which I need to remove. In fact, after the cleaning, I update the table to set the timestamp as the primary key.

Comment: @Jasen you are correct! I'm doing a `psql -c "COPY ... FROM STDIN` - if only I could add `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` then this wouldn't be necessary

Comment: So if two events happen at exactly the same time, you choose to ignore one of them? I hope you don't work for my bank.

Comment: @wildplasser you don't know anything about the problem domain that I'm working in here - so yes, for this particular problem, ignoring all but the last update is perfectly fine

Comment: in your example, you have four observations with tmestamp=`2021-02-01 08:00:00.123457+00` with three different sets of values. Which one(s) are you going to keep and why? And which one is *the last* ?

Comment: @wildplasser honestly, for my use case, it doesn't *really* matter. If I was being pedantic then I'd like to define the *last* one as the last one inserted (max `ctid` I assume? They are read from a Refinitiv tick history csv file using `zcat file | psql -c "COPY ... FROM STDIN"`), but equally, it doesn't really matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the hidden system column "ctid".

```
delete from test where exists 
    (select 1 from test as test2 where test2.time=test.time and test2.ctid>test.ctid)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's this sledgehammer

```
begin;
create temp table a on commit drop as select distinct on (time) * FROM test ORDER BY time;
truncate test;
insert into test select * from a;
commit;
```

Or using ctid to find the records to purge.

```
with a as ( select time ,min(ctid) from test group by time) 
delete from test using a 
where test.time=a.time and test.ctid > a.min;
```

Or the same with a subquery instead of CTE.

```
 delete from test 
 using ( select time ,min(ctid) from test group by test) as a
 where test.time=a.time and test.ctid > a.min;
```